# vector images in linux

Tags: software-rec, image-editor

Gimp cannot create vector images, is there a good linux application for this?

Comment: -1, lazy, unspecific and essentially useless as a stackexchang question.

Comment: @hop, do you want me to describe what a vector image is? Do you want to know that I would like it to work on gnome and kde? how is this unspesific? how is this useless?

Comment: illustrations, diagrams, from data, freehand, maybe even animated?

Comment: but I really don't want to know any of that...

Comment: @tshepang, I've no idea why I accepted that. Actually I don't think I would have... Anyway, acceptance awarded to highest rated answer. Which happens to be what I used in the end.

Comment: whats with all this thinking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is today the de facto standard. In earlier times, people used xfig and I still love it, however it isn't for the faint of heart as the user interface is disturbingly ugly and unusual (but highly efficient once you got to know it). Then there is also dia which is modeled a bit after xfig but with a normal Gtk GUI.

Comment: I'd chose xfig over Inkscape any day. At least it's been around long enough to get rid of crashing bugs.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I use xfig too. With it, e.g. I was able to copy my professors blackbord drawings in real time.

Comment: @hop maybe instead of giving a useless answer xfig and give links.

Comment: There is also asymptote (http://asymptote.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 10):

How about [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) ?

Answer (score 2):

I want to mention [Calligra Suite's](http://www.calligra-suite.org/) [Karbon](http://www.calligra-suite.org/karbon/), formerly [Koffice](http://www.koffice.org) [Karbon 14](http://www.koffice.org/karbon/), for [KDE](http://kde.org/). Fits in nicely with Any KDE/QT based desktop, in contrast to other Vector tools, though I'm not sure that it currently competes on features, or stability, but you'd have to try it to find that out.

To quote their features page

- Loading support for ODG, SVG, WPG, WMF, EPS/PS
- Writing support for ODG, SVG, PNG, PDF, WMF
- Customizable user interface with freely placable toolbars and dockers
- Layer docker for easy handling of complex documents including preview thumbnails, support for grouping shapes via drag and drop, controlling visibility of shapes or locking
- Advanced path editing tool with great on-canvas editing capabilies
- Various drawing tools for creating path shapes including a draw path tool, a pencil tool as well as a calligraphy drawing tool
- Gradient and pattern tools for easy on-canvas editing of gradient and pattern styles
- Top notch snapping facilities for guided drawing and editing (e.g. snapping to grid, guide lines, path nodes, bounding boxes, orthogonal positions, intersections of path shapes or extensions of lines and paths)
- Includes many predefined shapes including basic shapes like stars, circle/ellipse, rectangle, image
- Artistic text shape with support for following path outlines (i.e. text on path)
  Complex path operations and effects like boolean set operations, path flattening, rounding and refining as well as whirl/pinch effects
- Extensible by writing plugins for new tools, shapes and dockers