# Linux equivalent for Microsoft Visio?

Tags: software-rec, image-editor

Visio is a great tool for creating diagrams, flowcharts, prototyping, etc. But it is Windows-only and is not free. Are there any graphical tools for Linux that can do many of these same tasks well?

Comment: I would put `graphviz` as a serious answer, but I fear that I may get down-votes for it.

Comment: `graphviz` is the choice if you want to "generate" diagrams, I mean automatically. But if you want to draw interactively, then I think dia is great.

Comment: Right, I am really looking for an interactive tool.

Comment: See also [vector images in linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/vector-images-in-linux).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's Dia.. Not nearly as many features as Visio, but does diagrams: http://live.gnome.org/Dia

Answer (score 10):

How about Pencil?

http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx

Comment: Interesting... but this is only for prototyping?

Answer (score 8):

[diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net) works on Linux, is free and supports either local saving, or you can save Google Drive, OneDrive and Dropbox.

There is also a [desktop version](https://get.diagrams.net) with snap, AppImage, rpm and deb releases.

Comment: Cool, so this is basically an online Visio tool...

Answer (score 7):

[Kivio](http://www.kde.org/applications/office/kivio/), as the name kinda implies, is KDE's competitor to Visio. It is a part of the [KOffice](http://KOffice.Org/) suite.

Note: KOffice, as well as some of its applications were recently renamed. KOffice is now called *Calligra Suite* and Kivio is called [*Calligra Flow*](http://www.calligra-suite.org/flow/). However, there has not yet been a release since the rename.

Comment: Looks promising, I see a screenshot over here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calligra_Flow

Comment: page not found on Kivio.

Answer (score 4):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) is a cross-platform tool that can be used for prototyping.

[image: Sample WireframeSketcher mockup]

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to throw in [yED](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) which works on linux too, and has some nice features. It isn't GPL'd though,.

Comment: I would use Yed, its personal favorite. http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html

Answer (score 2):

For UML and DB Diagrams, you could use [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/).

Comment: UMLet is great.

Answer (score 2):

Although only for mySQL, the free mySQL workbench is a great tool that has filled this hole for me.  I can produce diagrams such as the following with it:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a nice way to create ER diagrams

Comment: yeah, that's what I was using Visio for myself.

Answer (score 2):

I have found LibreOffice Draw to be quite good. It is fast, actively being maintained and cross platform.

Comment: Thanks, this looks really nice: http://www.libreoffice.org/features/draw/screenshot-of-draw-the-libreoffice-image-editor/

Comment: Do you know if this has any support for importing visio files?

Comment: Looks like there is some, see 'filters' at: http://www.libreoffice.org/download/3-5-new-features-and-fixes/

Answer (score 1):

[Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/visio-linux-alternative) is an online alternative to Visio.  It imports and exports Visio files and has a free option.

Comment: The webpage says `Visio for Linux`. Nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the open source alternatives to visio here http://www.osalt.com/visio and any other equivalent for a commercial software

Answer (score 0):

I used "DIA" and "UMBRELLO", both fine, but not like Visio.

Answer (score -1):

I found [THIS](http://alternativeto.net/software/diagramly/) link, you should find all the alternatives there. good luck!